# dispatch_block_create - "No matching function for call to 'dispatch_block_create'"

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, objective-c++

I am trying to create a block using dispatch_block_create in a `.mm` file

```
dispatch_block_t testBlock = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
});
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1), dispatch_get_main_queue(), testBlock);
dispatch_block_cancel(testBlock);
```

And Xcode complains:

> No matching function for call to 'dispatch_block_create'

I have even tried adding:

```
#import <dispatch/block.h>
```

Comment: It is very strange... do you have the latest XCode version installed? Did you check you include UIKit? I tried your code right now and didn't have any build issue (no extra includes required!)
Try to make the usual cleanup: delete all derived data and restart xcode.

Comment: did you try it on a .mm file? The same works for me on .m file

Answer (score 3):

You left out a crucial part of the compiler error. I get:

```
foo.mm:6:34: error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch_block_create'
    dispatch_block_t testBlock = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/dispatch/block.h:171:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'dispatch_block_flags_t' for 1st argument
dispatch_block_create(dispatch_block_flags_t flags, dispatch_block_t block);
^
1 error generated.
```

The crucial part is **"candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'dispatch_block_flags_t' for 1st argument"**. It's due to the stricter type checking of (Objective-)C++. You need to explicitly cast `0` to `dispatch_block_flags_t`:

```
dispatch_block_t testBlock = dispatch_block_create(static_cast<dispatch_block_flags_t>(0), ^{ ... });
```